# Facebook Login Popup - Redirect Parent Page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-authentication

I am implementing the example at the bottom of the page from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) and i changed the script to read:

```
echo("<script> window.open('" . $dialog_url . "');</script>");
```

instead of:

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
```

So that the login opens in a new popup. How do I tell the popup to redirect the parent page? Right now the redirect is happening in the child page instead of the parent page.

Comment: Why don’t you just use FB.login from the JS SDK …?

Comment: I want to do it server side. It's easier for what I am trying to accomplish. Plus it gives me a longer access_token without having to make the extra call.

Comment: The you’ll have to close the popup window and reload the main page from your page that get’s loaded into the popup after login, I guess.

Comment: Umm... this does not look like javascript to me....

Comment: How though? My popup window goes to a Facebook page.

Comment: @Neal it's javascript in the script tags. I know it's PHP but my problem is a javascript problem.

Comment: _“My popup window goes to a Facebook page.”_ – then you have to make it go to a page of your own, by setting the redirect_uri value accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe syntactically how can I add that to the redirect_uri? is window.opener.location="myurl" legal?

Comment: @cbroe Facebook complains when I do that. Do you understand where that code is going? It is going in the url in a GET request. When i query facebook and include window.opener.location i get an error from facebook saying that it's not a proper URL.

Comment: Please show current code and quote original error message, otherwise there is no telling what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Usign this code for redirect parent window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.opener.location = 'your url'; window.close();
</script>
```

This code should be used in your popup window.
Good luck.

Comment: The popup window goes to Facebook though. It isn't something I control. My URL has the redirect URL in it and Facebook processes and then redirects to whichever URL i specified.

Comment: i use the following code for google openID sign up and sign in. when open a popup window and go to google page, after allow access by user, google redirect to your callback url! and i use this code in my callback url. it's different in facebook ?!

Comment: @hanleyhansen is right, you can add "window.opener.location..." to your callback url.